# Insert image from gallery to an array

Tags: android, arrays, imageview

I am trying to insert 3 images from my gallery from another activity to an `ArrayList` for a slider.

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_baseline_event_24,R.drawable.ic_baseline_event_24,R.drawable.ic_baseline_event_24};
```

I want to replace the `R.drawable` with `R.id.image` but I can't find any solutions.

Code to obtain images:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);   
intent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select image"),1);
```

Comment: i 've a doubt, where's the code when you obtain or select your images from your gallery?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select image"),1);

Comment: I'm new in Android studio and I'm exploring things.

Comment: Adding R.id.image will add the id of the image to the Array. i.e **It won't add images to the array.**

Comment: is there any way to add images to he array

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code to select multiple images from phone

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
```

Now if you are 100% sure user will only select multiple images then there is no need to place a check but just in case if user only selects one image its good to do so.

Inside onActivityResult if user selected multiple images `data.getData()` will return null
otherwise it will contain the Uri of the single image.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data.getData() == null) {
                //user selected multiple images
                int i = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                int j = 0;
                Uri[] imageUri = new Uri[i];
                Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[i]
                while (j < i) {
                    imageUri[j] = data.getClipData().getItemAt(j).getUri();
                    bitmap[j] = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri[i]);
                    j++;

               }
            }
            else
            {
            //User only selected one image
            }
        }
    }
```

With this code you will have an array of bitmap.

Note: you may have to surround bitmap with try catch.